Multithreaded push_back to std::vector: mutex, enlarge and edit in place, or create a vector for results and push it back?
Let's say we have an std::vector<Element> vec, which already has 200 elements. Then, we want to add count elements to it, and each element is created on the basis of a random old one (from the first 200):
for (int index = 0; index < count; index++) {
  vec.push_back(Element(vec[someRandomIndex(0, 200), ...]));
}

count is a very large number, let's say 200 as well, and the constructor of Element isn't trivial, so there is a benefit of making the push_back() of new Elements parallel. I see three ways to do this:

Resize vec and modify the elements in-place

vec.resize(vec.size() + count);
// this code will be split into chunks and each chunk 
// will be processed in a separate thread. No overlaps, so no data race. 
for (int index = 0; index < count; index++) {
  vec[200+index] = Element(vec[someRandomIndex(0, 200), ...]);
}


Create a vector of size count for the result, edit the elements of the vector in chunks and then push_back() the whole result vector to vec. This uses extra memory and the movement of the result vector to vec is linear in complexity.
Make an std::mutex for vec and put the push_back() call in a critical section. I prefer this method the least, as each write will be preceded by a read, in order to obtain a random old element for the creation of a new one.

Which technique will cause the least overhead? Is there a common practice for this? The number 200 is only an example and is likely to grow bigger.

count is a very large number, let's say 200 -- What type of objects are stored in the vector?  200 is tiny.  1 million or 2 million elements, that's a different story.

"Which technique will cause the least overhead?" instead of guessing you can implement and profile the options. Having said that, my guess is that option 1 will be the fastest.

Each Element contains an std::string of at least 300 characters and a float.

Still tiny. But the first option should be clearly the best. Even better if you batch the new elements to reduce false sharing.

@wohlstad I have a computer with 4GB of RAM and 2nd generation Core i5 CPU. This is only a small subset of the whole program, which is a genetic algorithm. I physically don't have the time , nor the resources, to profile all the options. I was hoping that a good choice can be made through logic and reasoning instead.

@SebastianRedl Thanks! It makes sense. I agree it's tiny, but I want to take benefit from the cache locality in the CPU. But what do you mean by "batching"?

@KotakaDanski "Batching" means not making one thread per job, but instead choose a fixed number of threads (typically number of physical threads, e.g. CPU cores or hyperthreads) and giving each a continuous range of elements to fill. Because memory access synchronization happens at cache line granularity, this reduces conflicts between the threads ("false sharing").

And while I would agree that profiling is the most reliable approach, writing "representative" benchmarks and profiling those is actually difficult enough (with the risk of getting it wrong and thus benchmarking the wrong thing) that just picking the obviously far superior first solution is the right thing to do in this case.

@SebastianRedl Oh, this is exactly what I was planning to do. Thanks! Would you like to post an answer, so that I can mark it as accepted?

"and the constructor of Element isn't trivial" resize does call a constructor. Consider to reserve and emplace back.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai Certainly. I already reserve() the necessary space in my original code, but I omitted this detail, because it wasn't as relevant to the question. Thanks!

@SebastianRedl despite what I wrote earlier I now tend to agree. I saw some cases in the past where the solution that seemed the fastest was not so in practice (and because of that recommended profiling). But in this case it would be quite surprising if option 1 wasn't the best one (with some improvments mentioned above).

@463035818_is_not_an_ai Be careful: you can concurrently access separate elements of a vector, but you cannot concurrently push_back, so using reserve+push/emplace_back puts you back into "I need to lock a mutex" territory. And you need to lock that mutex even when accessing the source object, because [] will race with push_back even if no reallocation happens and you only access existing elements.

Keep in mind that you can also put things like std::unique_ptr or std::shared_ptr into a container -- this not only means that the vector can be resized even while somebody is using an element, but often more importantly, the elements never move for their entire lifetime.

@SebastianRedl emplacing into a properly reserved vector does not need a mutex, because no reallocations take place.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai Of course it does. Two threads both emplacing into a vector race on the vector size, as they both increment it.

@SebastianRedl my fault. You are right. I got confused by the reference to push_back which I didnt mention, but in fact its the same problem

Don't try to guess what might be faster, write a benchmark and measure. There are some common patterns that often improve the performance, e.g. passing by const BigBoy& elem to avoid unnecessary copies, vec.reserve(KNOWN_SIZE); to avoid reallocations, memoization etc. But in your case we are talking about subtle differences in times needed to create new elements, access elements (potentially random?) already in the vector, and increasing the size of the vector.
So, write a benchmark, and measure!
#include <future>
#include <random>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <benchmark/benchmark.h>

// also check with 200 and see the difference
constexpr int HALF_SIZE = 10000;
// like you said, string with more than 200 characters
constexpr int STR_LEN = 1000;
// usually when number of workers exceed HW concurrency performance degenerates
constexpr int NUM_WORKERS = 4;

struct BigStructure {
  BigStructure() : str{} {}
  BigStructure(size_t num) : str(num, 'c') {}
  std::string str;
};

static void SerialVersion(benchmark::State &state) {
  std::random_device rd;
  std::mt19937 gen(rd());
  std::uniform_int_distribution<> distrib(0, HALF_SIZE - 1);
  std::vector<BigStructure> vec(HALF_SIZE);
  for (int i = 0; i < HALF_SIZE; i++) {
    // diversify the input a bit, but keep similar size
    if (i%2) vec[i] = BigStructure{STR_LEN};
    else vec[i] = BigStructure{STR_LEN-1};
  }
  vec.resize(2 * HALF_SIZE);
  for (auto _ : state) {
    for (int i = 0; i < HALF_SIZE; i++) {
      // also try to compare version without randomized indices
      vec[i] = BigStructure{vec[distrib(gen)].str.size()};
    }
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(vec);
  }
}
BENCHMARK(SerialVersion);

static void ThreadVersion(benchmark::State &state) {
  std::random_device rd;
  std::mt19937 gen(rd());
  std::uniform_int_distribution<> distrib(0, HALF_SIZE - 1);
  std::vector<BigStructure> vec(HALF_SIZE);
  for (int i = 0; i < HALF_SIZE; i++) {
    if (i%2) vec[i] = BigStructure{STR_LEN};
    else vec[i] = BigStructure{STR_LEN-1};
  }
  vec.resize(2 * HALF_SIZE);
  auto worker = [&vec, &distrib, &gen](int id) {
    constexpr int section = HALF_SIZE / NUM_WORKERS;
    int idxBegin = section * id;
    int idxEnd = idxBegin + section;
    for (int i = idxBegin; i < idxEnd; i++) {
      vec[HALF_SIZE + i] = BigStructure{vec[distrib(gen)].str.size()};
    }
  };
  for (auto _ : state) {
    std::vector<std::future<void>> workers;
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_WORKERS; i++) {
      workers.push_back(
          std::async(std::launch::async, [i, &worker]() { worker(i); }));
    }
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(vec);
  }
}
BENCHMARK(ThreadVersion);

On my PC there is no significant difference, and often threaded version is slightly slower. If I increase the number of elements in the vector to 1e6, threaded version becomes 3x faster. If I can avoid accessing random vector elements, it's also faster. On your older machine the benchmark might yield different results.
Google benchmark github.

Profiling is always a good idea as that gives the opportunity to look at what is 'actually' happening when the code is running. There's a few things to understand with this procedure.

When adding elements to a std::vector, the storage of the vector is a contiguous portion of memory. Everytime a new element is added, when the storage is full, the storage is re-allocated a larger portion of memory and the entire content of the storage is copy constructed in the new place, then the new element is added to the new storage. When this occurs often, this can eat CPU while putting elements into the vector. Avoid re-allocations by calling std::vector::reserve(N) before adding elements, where N is the new element count.
When inserting an element to a std::vector via push_back(), the element is constructed then copied. If the elements construction is non-trivial, it's faster to emplace_back() for a new element and std::move existing elements.
A call to std::vector::resize(N) default constructs N elements in memory.

While this is not a direct answer to the question, which method is best, I concur with the above comments that 200 elements is tiny unless the element constructor does serious heavy lifting. If there is signficant performance impact from this procedure, something else is likely going on. It would be necessary to find that underlying issue. My suggestions are only initial hints.

"When inserting an element to a std::vector via push_back(), the element is constructed then copied" - not true. If you do vec.push_back(Element{}); then 2nd overload void push_back( T&& value ); is selected and the temporary is moved into the new element. See: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back

If the Element supports move semantics, aka move constructor. That's not provided in the question.
